# Is the group $G$ always isomorphic to the group $G/N \times N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Is the group $G$ always
>   isomorphic to the group $G/N \times N$?

I don't think this is true but I can't think of a counter-example. What's an easy counter-example (or way to prove the contrary)?

Comment: This question should be asked in the site several times. Anyway, there is a very simple counterexample: consider the abelian group of order 4 and its proper subgroup.

Comment: @HanulJeon if you can find a duplicate of this question then please let me know and I will remove it.

Comment: How much work did you put into finding a counter-example? The conjecture fails for the smallest groups that have non-trivial subgroups!

Comment: Here is a relavant question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1142608/53976

Comment: @hardmath the hypothesis in that question assumes more than the hypothesis in this one. Here, we are only given that $N$ is a normal subgroup of some group $G$.

Comment: @user3749214:  Do the substitution of isomorphic groups:  $G$ is isomorphic to $G_1 \times G_2$ means $G$ isomorphic to $G/N \times N$.  There is extra notation ($G/N$ is isomorphic to $G_2$ and $N$ is isomorphic to $G_1$) but no assumption of additional hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the cyclic group of order $4$, say $C_{4}$. It has a nornal subgroup $H$ of index 2. $C_{4}/H$ is is a cyclic group of order $2$, isomorphic to $H$! But $H \times H$ is not cyclic!

Comment: Why is $C_4/H$ isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: @user3749214:  How many groups of order two do you know?

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new to group theory, and this site. @hardmath I understand there's only one cyclic group of order two but I don't understand how that implies $C_4/H$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Comment: @user3749214 There is only one group of order $2$ (cyclic or not). To see this, try filling out a Cayley table with two rows and columns. $C_4/H$ and $H$ are both groups of order $2$.

Comment: @TrevorNorton oh okay that makes sense. Lastly, I'm still not sure why $H \times H$ not being cyclic means $C_4$ isn't isomorphic to $C_4/H \times H$?

Comment: @user3749214 I think he was saying that since $C_4/H$ and $H$ are isomorphic, we can say that $C_4/H \times H$ is isomorphic to $H\times H$. Since $H\times H$ is not cyclic, neither is $C_4/H\times H$. We can then conclude that since $C_4$ *is* cyclic, that $C_4$ and $C_4/H\times H$ cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Think of the smallest non-abelian group you can. Can you find a normal subgroup of this?

Comment: Why torment the OP with non-abelian groups?

Comment: Haha, because I could not think of $C_4$ until mich95 pointed it out. And I think generally $S_3$ is a useful toy to have in the back of one's mind while doing group theory instead of just the cyclic groups..