# Isomorphism Between Group and Direct product of normal subgroup and Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be its normal subgroup.
Is $G \cong H \times G/H$ ?
Any counter-example if it is not true?

Comment: Have you checked it for cyclic groups?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. so I let $G=C_4$ and $H=C_2$. Then it follows that $C_2 \times C_4/C_2 \cong C_2 \times C_2$. and thus G is not isomorphic to H.

Comment: You may or may not want [Schur-Zassenhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem) which states that $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and $G/H$ under certain conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is $G \cong H \times G/H$ ?

No, actually this is quite rare situation, even among abelian groups. The simpliest counterexample is the cyclic group of order $4$: $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$, $H=\{0,2\}$. Note that $G/H\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2\simeq H$ but $G$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ since the latter has no element of order $4$.

Comment: thanks! by the way, just wondering is there any condition on the group will make this true.

Comment: @AndyKang you may want to read this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142608/when-is-a-group-the-product-of-its-subgroup-and-their-factor-group