# If $G=H\times K$ then can we view $G/K$ as $H$?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

Here $K$ is identified as $\{1\}\times K$. I think because $G/K$ does not depend on $H$, it is natural to say that $G/K$ and $H$ is isomorphic.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723707/how-is-the-quotient-group-related-to-the-direct-product-group

Comment: This is correct. You could write out the isomorphism.

Comment: In particular consisder the projection $\pi(g,h) = h$